# Trying to Run a unit test, but getting the following error: AssertionError: expected '0xCAEc8498aB11D596116B5175017B9Ab220b…' to equal undefined

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ethers.js, hardhat, unittesting

I am trying to write a unit test for the simple condition of checking the owner's address once the contract is deployed.

The unit test code for this is as follows:

````
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("SmartWallet Testing", function()
{
    it("Check Owner", async function()
    {
     const Owneradd = await ethers.getSigners();
     const SmartWallet = await ethers.getContractFactory("SmartWallet");
     const deploy = await SmartWallet.deploy();
     
     expect(await deploy.owner()).to.equal(Owneradd.address);
    });
});```

The error I encounter is **AssertionError: expected '0xCAEc8498aB11D596116B5175017B9Ab220b…' to equal undefined**

I am using the Signer function to get a default address, but not sure why it doesn't work.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the incorrect way of getting the owner's address using getSigners()
As getSigners() function will return multiple signers so first you need to get the owner from getSigners().

```js
//destructuring owner from getSigners  
const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
```

Now you can use expect to test

```js
expect(await deploy.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
```

Your entire it block should look like

```js
    it('Check Owner', async function () {
            const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
            const SmartWallet = await ethers.getContractFactory('SmartWallet');
            const deploy = await SmartWallet.deploy();
            expect(await deploy.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, Neeraj that was really helpful, I figured this out last night and came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with:

```
  const deployeAddress = await deploy.owner()
  expect(deployerAddress).to.equal(Owneradd.address);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I have another question, If I have deployed a contract using the deploy() method, and I want to get the contract address of the deployed contract what can I do?